# Does the keyword volatile in Java force memory synchronization on single core machine?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile, memory-barriers

If I understand it correctly, volatile is causing memory barrier that synchronises local memory with main memory. That is pretty useful on multi core machines.

Will this memory synchronisation happen when a multi threaded application is running on single core machine?

Comment: On a single CPU machine, there is nothing to synchronize.  On a single core machine with hyper threading, it will force the data to cache so the other thread can see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will this memory synchronisation happen when a multi threaded application is running on single core machine?

Yes.  `volatile` causes a read and/or write memory barrier and ensures a "happens-before" relationship when another thread is accessing the same `volatile` field.  See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html).  It ensures that changes to the local CPU cache are written to main memory and that changes to main memory invalidate any CPU cache pages.

This is less important on a single-processor box since there is only one CPU cache to worry about.  However, it is important to realize that the "happens-before" guarantees with `volatile` are still important.  They prevent race conditions that could happen even if there is only one CPU because of time slicing with multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

> Will this memory synchronisation happen when a multi threaded application is running on single core machine?

Yes.

Comment: what do you mean? I don't get it

Comment: @gomul - he means "Yes".